# Missing library while installing ruby-filemagic gem on Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I needed gem ruby-filemagic for some requirements in my project. While running bundle install its giving me this error

```
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: You don't give much information, what is the platform? Windows, Linux, Mac?  Does it fail on a specific Gem?  Sometimes Gems which need to compile need header files, so that may be an issue.

Comment: please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190961/trying-to-install-ruby-filemagic-on-snow-leopard-using-brew-rather-than-ports

Comment: @hwatkins: i am using linux, I have already mentioned the gem name

Comment: Which Linux OS are you installing on?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libmagic-dev` did it for me

Answer (score 39):

Running `brew install libmagic` before `gem install ruby-filemagic` on OSX made my installation of ruby-filemagic successful.

Comment: I'm here again on the same answer to thank you. Saved my life twice.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you install gem ruby-filemagic on an EC2 instance, login as root and use this command

```
yum install file file-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an **alpine** distribution and cannot use apt-get, try this:

`apk add musl libmagic file file-dev imagemagick`