# Unable to install ruby-filemagic 0.7.1 on Mac even though libmagic has been installed

Tags: ruby, libmagic

Unable to install ruby-filemagic 0.7.1 on Mac even though libmagic has been installed.

The error is like :

checking for main() in -lgnurx... no

checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no

*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Almost all answers fo ruby-filemagic installation are the `brew install libmagic`. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190961/trying-to-install-ruby-filemagic-on-snow-leopard-using-brew-rather-than-ports) might be helpful?

Comment: A few hours were cost before I found the problem. Let me write it down here:

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Monterey 12.0.1 helped this:

`brew unlink libmagic && brew link libmagic`

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` - in case you have Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

`gem install ruby-filemagic -v '0.7.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-magic-include=/opt/homebrew/include --with-magic-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/`

Answer (score -1):

A few hours were cost before I found the problem. Let me write down the cause and solution here :

#### cause:

my `ruby` (`$HOME/.rbenv/versions/x.x.x/bin/ruby`) was under the control of `rbenv`, however my `bundler` was controlled by old `ruby` (`/usr/local/ruby`) .
The stupid `bundler` could not find the library for installing `ruby_filemagic` and wasted so much time.

#### solution:

`$ rbenv exec gem install bundler
$ rbenv rehash`

make `bundler`, `gem`, `ruby` under the same management.

Sorry for my poor English. I hope this may help more people.