# fail to install ruby-filemagic 0.7.2 on mac m1 big sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Install ruby-filemagic 0.7.2 fail
I'm using mac M1 Bigsur ver 11.5.2

what i already try :

brew install libmagic

already installed but still fail to install ruby-filemagic

here is the log :

```
    current directory: /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/ext/filemagic
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210907-83349-1lgxyp3.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lgnurx... no
checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-magic-dir
    --without-magic-dir
    --with-magic-include
    --without-magic-include=${magic-dir}/include
    --with-magic-lib
    --without-magic-lib=${magic-dir}/lib
    --with-gnurx-dir
    --without-gnurx-dir
    --with-gnurx-include
    --without-gnurx-include=${gnurx-dir}/include
    --with-gnurx-lib
    --without-gnurx-lib=${gnurx-dir}/lib
    --with-gnurxlib
    --without-gnurxlib
    --with-magiclib
    --without-magiclib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ruby-filemagic (0.7.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-filemagic -v '0.7.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  ruby-filemagic
```

log from :  /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/mkmf.log

```
have_library: checking for -lgnurx... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/-darwin20 -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.6   "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/-darwin20 -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.6 -lgnurx   "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'
ld: library not found for -lgnurx
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
14: 
15: int t(void) { ; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/-darwin20 -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.6 -lmagic   "
conftest.c:14:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'magic_open'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/-darwin20 -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.6 -lmagic   "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'
ld: library not found for -lmagic
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
14: extern void magic_open();
15: int t(void) { magic_open(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

can somebody help me, I got stuck on this ...
*notes ---
as information i use rbenv before , is it possible that it causes conflict or something ? now i use rmv

Comment: The error message says: `library not found for -lmagic`. Have you tried `brew install libmagic`?

Comment: yes i already install libmagic
here is log when i try to run brew install libmagic 

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (shivammathur/php, homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
age
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 11 formulae.
==> Updated Casks
Updated 2 casks.

Warning: libmagic 5.40 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 5.40, run:
  brew reinstall libmagic

Comment: i think gem cannot found the libmagic, but i dont know why

Comment: You might need to explicitly specify the folder location, e.g. `--with-magic-dir=/opt/local`

Comment: i found the folder location on this path :  `/opt/homebrew/opt/libmagic `
what should i do next ?

Comment: DONE with : `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install ruby-filemagic -- --with-magic-include=/usr/local/include --with-magic-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/libmagic`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I was able to install it by using the following command from [a comment on a gist](https://gist.github.com/eparreno/1845561#gistcomment-3813020)

`gem install ruby-filemagic -v '0.7.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-magic-include=/opt/homebrew/include --with-magic-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/`

There are other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190961/trying-to-install-ruby-filemagic-on-snow-leopard-using-brew-rather-than-ports) that include `--with-magic-include=/opt/homebrew/include --with-magic-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/`

It did not work without the `--source 'https://rubygems.org/'` flag.

Comment: Please add link of other questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: added a link in the answer

Comment: Thank alot. It's work for me.
`
gem install ruby-filemagic -v '0.7.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-magic-include=/opt/homebrew/include --with-magic-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/

`

Answer (score 2):

```sh
gem install ruby-filemagic -v 0.7.2 -- \
  --with-magic-lib=$(brew --prefix)/lib \
  --with-magic-include=$(brew --prefix)/include
```